# Windows Phone 8 using PNS authenticated web service for an enterprise app

Tags: web-services, authentication, windows-phone-8, push-notification, enterprise

We have an enterprise app using MS PNS that is managed via a 3p MDM (airwatch).

The app will NOT be deployed via the MS phone store and I need to enable PNS using an authenticated web service without the 4 month development window as stated here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941099(v=vs.105).aspx).

As per the MSDN article noted above the certificate would become invalid after the 4 month development window if the app is not published to the store and since the app WILL NOT be published to the store I'm not sure how to make use of MS PNS without hitting the per channel limit as per this documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941100(v=vs.105).aspx) which results in a "406 not acceptable".

Our goal is to have an enterprise app deployed using a 3p MDM (not via the MS phone app store) that has an unlimited PNS limit to each enterprise device.  Can this goal be met somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no way. Based on my understanding of the documentation, the authenticated channel only works for apps published through the store. I would love to be proved wrong here. :-)

The recent [leaked Windows Phone Blue screenshots](http://www.theverge.com/2013/6/8/4408798/windows-phone-notification-center-screenshots-leak-rumor) hint that Microsoft is improving the notification service, including the user experience on the phone. So there is hope for the future version at least...